# Hangfire Cron Job Does Not execute on Actual Cron Time

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am executing multiple jobs using hangfire(once per day) at different Time interval.
Job 1- 1 AM UTC
Job 2 - 4 AM UTC

Sometimes randomly both Jobs 1 and 2 execute at same time. Could any one tell me the reason for this ?

Comment: Do you specify the timezone when you en queue the Hangfire job?

Comment: The other possibility is that IIS goes into "sleep" mode. see -> 
http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html

Comment: Thanx Pieter..Yes IIS was on sleep mode, I have again configured it as always running mode..It worked for me